# Does Perl 6 have named tuples?

Tags: raku

I know that Swift has named tuples:

```
let twostraws = (name: "twostraws", password: "fr0st1es")
```

so I can say:

```
print(twostraws.name)  # twostraws
```

but in Perl 6 I'd say:

```
my $list = (twostraws, fr0st1es);
say $list[0];
```

Which is not as awesome as Swift, so I want to know if there are named tuples in Perl 6?

Comment: Are you looking for a Hashmap?

Comment: @zb226 

`my $name       = "twostraws";
my $password = "fr0st1es";

my $list            = (:name($name), :password($password));

say $list[0]{'name'};`
is this **HashMap**?

Comment: It is a [List](https://doc.perl6.org/type/List) of [Pair](https://doc.perl6.org/type/Pair)s. You can see the type by doing e.g. `say $list[0].WHAT;`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are various ways of getting something similar.

- Simple hash ( recommended )

  ```perl6
  my \twostraws = %( 'name' => 'twostraws', 'password' => 'fr0st1es' );
  print twostraws<name>; # twostraws{ qw'name' }
  ```

- List with two methods mixed in

  ```perl6
  my \twostraws = ( 'twostraws', 'fr0st1es' ) but role {
    method name     () { self[0] }
    method password () { self[1] }
  }

  put twostraws.name; # `put` is like `print` except it adds a newline
  ```

- Anonymous class

  ```perl6
  my \twostraws = class :: {
    has ($.name, $.password)
  }.new( :name('twostraws'), :password('fr0st1es') )

  say twostraws.name; # `say` is like `put` but calls the `.gist` method
  ```

There are probably quite a few more that I haven't thought of yet. The real question is how you are going to use it in the rest of your code.

Comment: Wow, Perl 6 is so flexible!

Comment: @chenyf Actually you can write your code in any language that someone has written a Slang for. ( So in effect, all other languages could be considered a subset of Perl 6 ) If you were going to write a lot of them you could write a Circumfix operator for it `sub circumfix:<\` \`> ( @ ($name,$password)) { %( :$name, :$password ) }; say \` 'twostraws', 'fr0st1es' \`<name>`

Answer (score 6):

Enums can have value types that are not Int. You declare them as a list of Pairs.

```
enum Twostraws (name => "twostraws", password => "fr0st1es");
say name; # OUTPUT«twostraws␤»
say password; # OUTPUT«fr0st1es␤»
say name ~~ Twostraws, password ~~ Twostraws; # OUTPUT«TrueTrue␤»
say name.key, ' ', name.value; # OUTPUT«name twostraws␤»
```

The type that is declared with `enum` can be used just like any other type.

```
sub picky(Twostraws $p){ dd $p };
picky(password); # OUTPUT«Twostraws::password␤»
```

Edit: see https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/master/S12-enums/non-int.t

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the type in Perl 6 that you are looking for is a hash.

See the relevant documentation:

- [Syntax: "Hash literals"](http://doc.perl6.org/language/syntax#Hash_literals)
- [Hash](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Hash)

Here is a Perl 6 example that should be equivalent to your Swift example:

```
my %twostraws = name => 'twostraws', password => 'fr0st1es';

print %twostraws<name>; # twostraws
```

Comment: Some supplemental documentation: [Syntax: "String literals"](https://doc.perl6.org/language/syntax#String_literals) (single quotes versus double quotes in Perl 6).

Answer (score 3):

The perl6 equivalent is the [Pair](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Pair) type and its constructor operator is [=>](http://doc.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_%3D%3E).  They are immutable - once created the key and value can't be changed;

```
$ perl6
> my $destination = "Name" => "Sydney" ;
Name => Sydney
> say $destination.WHAT ;
(Pair)
> $destination.value = "London";
Cannot modify an immutable Str
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

>
```

Like the "fat comma" from perl5, the constructor doesn't require the left-hand side to be quoted if it's a single identifier.  There is an alternative syntax for expressing Pairs called "colon pair".  You can collect a number of Pairs togeather into a list but they will only be accessible positionaly;

```
> $destination = ( Name => "Sydney" , :Direction("East") , :Miles(420) );
(Name => Sydney Direction => East Miles => 420)
> say $destination.WHAT ;
(List)
> say $destination[1] ;
Direction => East
>
```

There are convenient variants of the colon pair syntax - if the value is a string, you can replace the parentheses with angle brackets and drop the quotes.  If the value is an integer, you can list the key immediately *after* the value without quotes. If the value is boolean, you can list the key alone if the value is True or prefixed with `!` if the value is False.

Finally, you can assign a number of them into a hash where the values can be accessed by key and are mutable;

```
> my %destination = ( :Name<Sydney> , :Direction<East> , :420miles , :!visited ) ;
Direction => East, Name => Sydney, miles => 420, visited => False
> say %destination<miles> ;
420
> %destination<visited> = True ;
True
>
```